# SQLite Fetch a weekly recursive date

Tags: sql, sqlite, knex.js

I need some help on this particular problem (I can't change the table structure) :

I have a table of `events` in SQLite

| Kind | Start | End | Weekly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Opening | 2020-01-01 09:00 | 2020-01-01 09:30 | true |

A record is stored with a knexClient in javascript :

```js
await knexClient("events").insert([
        {
          kind: "opening",
          starts_at: new Date("2020-01-01 09:00").toISOString(),
          ends_at: new Date("2020-01-01 09:30").toISOString(),
          weekly_recurring: true,
        },
```

A weekly event occurs every week at the day + 7 and at the same hours.

- 2020-01-01 09:00 - 2020-01-01 09:30
- 2020-01-08 09:00 - 2020-01-08 09:30
- 2020-01-15 09:00 - 2020-01-15 09:30
- ...

What I need is to fetch this record when I ask this question : `Get me the openings for 2020-01-08`

What i tried so far :

```js
knexClient('events')
        .where('kind', 'opening')
        .whereRaw("(julianday(?) - julianday(starts_at)) % 7 = 0", [date.toISOString()])
        .select('starts_at', 'ends_at');
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many product have their own date/time functions.)

Comment: You want to consider the start date only for the given date?

Comment: Actually it's an in memory db (sqlite3 to be precise) and i'm using a knex client (in javascript) to get into it. The dates are just regular dateTime format :)